# TFS / SSDT Deployment in Multi Environment Scenario

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

This is the scenario I am currently experiencing.
In Development environment, developers usually make changes in the DEV SQL Server, then they will do a schema compare in Visual Studio 2013 / TFS, update the TFS then check the changes in.

Now, say in DEV, there are many stored procedures in a database that refer to a database called A, however in SIT environment this database is called B.

When I want to deploy these stored procedures from TFS to the SIT environment, is there a (automated) way to replace database A to database B, so that the stored procs do not break in SIT?

The workaround that I did was that I generated the publish script (via TFS > Publish > Generate Script), then copy and paste that script to SSMS, replace all reference to database A with database B.
However, this is quite manual (and not foolproof - have to be really careful what to replace), so I am wondering if there is a feature/capability to do this exercise in more efficient manner?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Publish Profiles and Project Variables would be the first things that come to mind. Publish Profiles to make it easier to standardize the options. Project variables to use to store the name of the DB.  (If referring to an external DB, you can set these up w/ the DB reference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a functionality for that, but it might require some significant changes in your workflow.

You can use SQL Server database projects in SSDT to store database code. In this case, you can declare a project-level variable with the complementary database name, and then reference its objects in your SSDT project using SQLCMD syntax.

Or better yet, you can create projects for both databases and add the latter's DACPAC file as an external reference to the former. It will create a corresponding SQLCMD variable automatically and will make Intellisense available for linked database' objects.

During deployment, you can generate the publish script with changes and update only the value of this SQLCMD variable in the beginning of the publish script.

Of course, this approach requires that all changes in databases should be introduced in SSDT projects first and deployed to actual instances later. However, benefits far outweigh the additional hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Roger Wolf. 

If I understand it correctly, your suggestions will involve making changes to all database objects, e.g. all stored procs to ensure they are using SQLCMD variables.
Is this correct?

Comment: @iKnowNothing, yes - exactly the same changes you make now when you need to deploy them into a different environment. Only this time you will need to do it only once, in the database project code.

Comment: Is there a way to (bulk) update database objects in TFS so that they are using SQLCMD variables? Something like for example create a script for all database objects in a database project, then update database references to use SQLCMD variables, then somehow store/save them back to TFS. Is there such a way?

Comment: I don't think so. Creating new database project, importing schema from existing database, mass replacing external references with corresponding SQLCMD variables and then putting that project into TFS, cutting off legacy of previous scripts preferably - that's how I would do it. I don't know how you store your schema now, but formats will be too different most likely. That's why I said it can be a breaking change.

Comment: how to do the mass replacing external references? Is there an option when importing schema from existing database to a new database project?

Comment: Ctrl+H in Visual Studio? Just like with any other type of project? Remember, you don't have to do this every time - only once, when you move DB schema development into SSDT. However, you need to force all developers to stop developing on databases and move to SSDT projects, as well.

Comment: Do you mean after importing schema to SSDT, I have to click each database objects one by one in SSDT and change the database references? 

What if from SSMS, I use Generate Scripts > script all the database objects, then change the database references in the script to use SQLCMD variables, then in SSDT Database Project > Import > Script(.sql). Would that work?

Comment: In SSDT project, all database objects are represented by .sql files that contain their definitions. As such, you don't have to "script" them one by one, since they are already in this form. And if you open the Find / Replace window in VS and select "All files in project / solution", you can replace one external reference at a time, project-wide.

Comment: I noticed that if I use SQLCMD variable like [$(DatabaseName)] in the script inside SSDT / VS, the Intellisense does not work. Any ideas how to get Intellisense work while referencing database name with SQLCMD variable?

Comment: Normally, there is no point in using it, because the variable `$(DatabaseName)` points to the database of the current project. All external databases, however, usually resolved by Intellisense - at least in VS 2015.

Comment: It's just because now that I ask all developers to develop in SSDT (rather than in SSMS) and using SQLCMD variables to refer to database name in the script, devs will find it annoying that Intellisense does not work, e.g. table names, column names, etc do not come up after putting '.' (dot). Also, I noticed that I have to use the square brackets for the SQLCMD variables, e.g. [$(Database)] rather than $(Database), otherwise when building the project, it will fail. Is that as per design?

Comment: Square brackets aren't necessary per se, but I think it's Visual Studio that makes them mandatory.

Comment: Regarding Intellisense, did you add your other databases as external references to your project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj684584.aspx

Comment: Yes, now I can get it working @Roger Wolf! Thanks for your assistance! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to continue using the *connected* workflow to edit your database, you may like to consider using synonyms in your database: instead of using a 3-part reference, which may change depending on the environment you're deploying to, you can put the variable part into the synonym and keep the contents of the stored procedure static.

In order to do so, you would need to start by creating a synonym for each table that you want to reference across database boundaries, e.g.

`CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Syn_MyTable] FOR [$(OtherDb)].[dbo].[MyTable]`

Then, in place of the table names, reference the synoynms in your procs e.g.:

`CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc AS
    SELECT ID FROM [Syn_MyTable]`

Even with this method in place, the caveat is that you'll still be going against the grain if you try to follow this kind of workflow with SSDT, as SSDT is primarily a *disconnected* database editing tool. For example, if using schema compare to bring the changes into the project from your development environments, it's possible that SSDT will see changes to the synonyms if the destination database name differs. So special care is needed to ensure that the variable syntax within your project's synonym definition is not overwritten.

An alternate approach to database development is supported by a product we make at Redgate called ReadyRoll. ReadyRoll is a project sub-type of SSDT which actually favours a connected editing workflow. For example, with ReadyRoll, if you use a synonym, then it will ignore any differences in the database reference when importing changes into your project (as these are treated as variable by nature).

You can read more about how synonyms work in ReadyRoll, including a sample project, on this forum post:
https://forums.red-gate.com/viewtopic.php?f=199&t=79564&sid=314391978c186c19e50d9d69f266a700

Comment: Thanks Dan. Does this mean I'd need to modify all stored procs to ensure they use the created synonyms (rather than using 3-part naming convention)?

Comment: @iKnowNothing I'm afraid so unfortunately